# PHP Session Serialize Object

Tags: php, php-7

I've found a lot of information on session serialization from PHP 5.4 and below, but not much for PHP 7. A couple years ago I was advised to use `$_SESSION['var'] = serialize($object);` when storing a class variable (`class object { public $value; function __construct() { $this->value = new object2(); }}`).

Today, I transitioned my code from one development environment to another. The new one seems to dislike `= serialize($object);` but appears to be fine with `= $object`.

A few weeks ago I ran across a few posts that mentioned PHP always serializes variables before putting them into sessions, and since this event (During today's search), I've found many of those same posts.

In PHP's documentation, I ran across a mention of `session_register()`, which apparently was supposed to be used to store objects in session variables... but it was apparently discontinued in 5.3.

Previous testing taught me that assigning session variables with class variables without serializing them first doesn't seem to keep track of class variables well, in particular situations like the above, where a variable is another class variable (object2).

The problems I had seemed hit-and-miss, and was in fact the reason I went looking for an answer and found serialize to begin with, and once I added serialize/unserialize (And no other changes), everything worked as intended.

So, here's my question: What's the 'real' way to handle object serialization for PHP sessions?

`$_SESSION['var'] = serialize($object);` causes a 500 error. `$_SESSION['var'] = $object` doesn't have an error, but due to previous issues, I'm not sure how well it works.

While on the topic, what's the best approach for unserializing? `$object = unserialize($_SESSION['var']);` is my current approach. It doesn't result in an error, but for the sake of possible minor optimization and future knowledge, might as well cover the base.

If my approach (Using `serialize()` and `unserialize()`) is correct, what setting(s) would cause `serialize()` to fail?

If there are any typos in any 'code' piece here, I wrote them inline in the post, so ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

You can save objects in sessions like any other value. At the end of the script the session got [serialized and saved](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) anyway:

> When PHP shuts down, it will automatically take the contents of the `$_SESSION` superglobal, serialize it, and send it for storage using the session save handler.

The "main" problem is that for loading the session again the class definition for the object you try to load must be available/loaded **before** using the `session_start();` call. Other than that everything should work just fine.

For your 500 server error, you have to check the error message and/or error log what the problem is.

Comment: The 500 error was actually due to trying to serialize a PDO instance, so that part's fixed... but the behavior I was getting related to the sessions before indicated the class variables weren't being properly stored. So although $_SESSION may be serialized at the end of the script, there may be an issue if a class variable (Specifically) isn't serialized -prior- to storage in $_SESSION? I'm not sure, I just know the behavior was "forgetful" and somewhat unpredictable until I serialized before storing in session.